# Why is not my `find` command working?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

What is this and why is this not listing files that have "idea" in their names?

```
/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents$ find . "*idea*" -exec echo aaa {} \; | head
aaa .
aaa ./_CodeSignature
aaa ./_CodeSignature/CodeResources
aaa ./bin
aaa ./bin/fsnotifier
aaa ./bin/idea.properties
aaa ./bin/inspect.sh
aaa ./bin/libbreakgen.dylib
aaa ./bin/libbreakgen.jnilib
aaa ./bin/libbreakgen64.dylib
find: *idea*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `-name` test:

```
find . -name "*idea*" -exec echo aaa {} \;
```

Without `-name`:

```
find . "*idea*" -exec echo aaa {} \;
```

is `find`-ing all files/directories, on current directory (`.`), and file/directory matched by `*idea*` in the current directory, recursively. Presumably, there is no file/directory with `idea` in their names in the current directory, hence the error regarding `*idea*`.

---

As a side note, if you are looking for only files, add `-type f`:

```
find . -name "*idea*" -type f -exec echo aaa {} \;
```

Comment: Exactly. We've answered my question simultaneously. Upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: That's why I upvoted :-) Will accept, too, once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I've forgotten the `-name` parameter. This command is listing all contents of the `.` folder, following by all context of the (non-existent)  `"*idea*"` folders.